# Drools rule names in console output

Tags: drools

I want to see in console output rule names, but now I see only row number where this rule is defined. How can I change it? I use decision table and KieServices.

Comment: There is a rule for each row in your decision table. Therefore each rule is named based on the row in which it is found. What you are seeing **is** the rule name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule name is composed from the string after RuleTable, the cell indicating the start of another decision table, an underscore, and the row number. For instance:

```
  20    RuleTable Foo
  21
  22
  23
  24
  25    --------------------- results in rule Foo_25
```

You could produce the rule name in its row using a formula:

```
  =CONCATENATE("Foo_", ROW())
```

It's also possible to determine the rule name at runtime using right hand side features to access the Rule being executed.

Comment: For example, [pick from drools docs](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.3.0.Final/drools-expert-docs/html/images/Chapter-Decision_Tables/excel.png). First rule in this table have name "Catastrophic claim". Can I see this in console instead of rule "_17"?

Comment: The entries in column B are just "decoration" and not automatically compiled into the rule. You could use a spreadsheet expression to copy it into an action column where it can be picked up by a println or whatever.